# Broken spark plug stuck/seized in place

Tags: electrical, maintenance, sparkplugs, repair, replace

Changing spark plugs to a 2002 chevy cavalier last one broken and stuck! Tried soaking with wd40 & PB Blaster but still not moving...any advice?

Comment: Yes..what is proper way to extract a btoken sparkplug?

Comment: Click on the link ... there are instructions in the answers there.

Comment: Only the threaded portion remains stuck inside

Comment: Use an [extractor kit](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bolt%20extractor%20kit)?